# How to make a table containing history of imported excel files

Tags: c#, sql, excel, asp.net-mvc, import

I have watched videos on youtube on how to import excel data to my table and made it work on my code. But my problem is I want to show history of imported excel files using another table.

[This is what my table looks when I import excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iljsl.png)

I want to get the name of the file and show it on another table to make a table of history or logs of imported files

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to achieve, what the problem is you are facing and where you're stuck. Please give more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new Table and whenever somebody imports an Excel File you also add a new Entry in the history table with for example the current DateTime and a Foreign Key to the Excel Table.

Comment: But if I make a foreign key it will be repetitive. Example 1 foreign key in ExcelTableHistory (History table) and ExcelTableID in StudentTable column (The table that will be imported). Each student will have the same key